# bootstraping multiple sprint boot servlets

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-7

I have a complex application with multiple (5) modules, following micro services architecture. Each module is using spring boot, but in the end we are manually copying the war of every module to tomcat. And manually starting the tomcat server.

Is there any way for me to deploy / start all the 5 modules as part of same embedded tomcat instance that comes along with Spring boot? To be more elaborate, Can I bootstrap all the spring boot applications as part of same embedded tomcat instance?

Answer (score 0):

No. You would need to convert them to `war`'s and deploy to a non embedded tomcat.